# How can the angel of death (Hazrat Izraeel) be present at more than one locations at the same time if more than 1 person die at that same time?

Tags: malaikah

I am a Muslim by religion, and I always feel exhilirated when I research about the history of Islam and its teachings. I am an Aerospace Engineer by profession.

I have heard that Hazrat Izraeel is the angel of death according to the teachings of Islam, or in other words, Angel of death. I don't exactly know where is this fact written; it could be in Quran itself or maybe we know about this through Ahadis. But my question is that how can Hazrat Izraeel be present at more than one locations, if for example, 10 people die in this world at exactly the same time. It doesn't practically make sense near me. Or I am missing something. Would be glad to enlighten myself with this knowledge.

Comment: Is the angel of death's name Izraeel? or even Azraeel? Is there any proof of this?

Comment: @Rameez At the onset, please understand that the concept of time is not absolute but relative in nature. Once you are able to research into this (Look into theory of relativity by Einstein) .. . you will understand that time runs at differently for different objects. This fact is well  documented in the events of Isra and Mi'raj. Closer to our time, you can also look into how identical clocks on the satellites are ticking more slowly than Earth-based clocks .

Comment: @Ahmed, well since you mentioned it, I am a physics enthusiast as well in my free time. Time is relative, that is true. But for two normal human beings, time is still the same. Its just that any object if travelling at a speed of light, time stops for him. Yes, but only for him (which might be possible for Angel Azraeel) but not for the world. How can their souls be taken away at the same time, well this confuses me.

Comment: The qur'an informs us that for each of us there's an angel of death who shall be ordered to come to us at our moment of death. So there's no issue here. Further there are only a couple of named angels who are authentic and agreed upon, so just because somebody claimed there's an angel of death this doesn't mean that others do this task too nor that 'Azraeel or whatever his name is is only the leader of these angels of death....

Comment: @RameezUlHaq Glad to hear to you are into physics. Please look into 'Heisenberg's uncertainty principle' & the 'Double-slit experiment' .. I know that quantum physics is counter intuitive and is usually applied to very very minute elements that make up the atoms and it's constituents. But it is a good starting point to understand how Allah in His Infinite Wisdom and Power has given different rules for different dimensions. And Angels are from the Ghaib (Unseen)..

Comment: hence, we can't truly understand how they can travel billions of light years in an instant or appear in multiple locations at the same time. But theoretical physics gives us a good starting point to make some educated guesses. In the end, Allah is powerful and He does what He wills.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualykumwarahmatullahiwabarakatuhu,

The first thing to note is that lots of Islamic beliefs are illogical to the human brain as it does not have the capacity to understand divine things. Pondering over such things are completely natural, but you should remember that Allah controls the angel. Allah created a perfect universe with ease so He can allow an angel to be in multiple places at the same time. If you think about the might and power of Allah, such things are minute compared to others like the creation of man, jannah and jahannam etc.